# Transact-SQL Comma Separated Values Not Sorted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to control the output of this query to return the values sorted from lower to higher values. As you can see on the last line of the results below I'm getting 16,15,1 as the result, but I need to get 1,15,16 as the result.

Below is the script I'm currently using. I would appreciate any help I can get. Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT STUFF ((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(max), UserId)
FROM MessageRecipients mr2
WHERE mr1.ConversationId = mr2.ConversationId FOR xml path('')), 1, 1,'') AS 'Result'
FROM MessageRecipients mr1
GROUP BY ConversationId
```

This is the result I get with the current script (column name 'result'):

```
1,19
1,15
16,15,1
```

Comment: The inner `SELECT` query doesn't have any `ORDER BY` clause - therefore, **no ordering** is guaranteed.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an ORDER BY to the inner SELECT:

```
SELECT STUFF (
    (SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(max), UserId)
        FROM MessageRecipients mr2
        WHERE mr1.ConversationId = mr2.ConversationId 
        ORDER BY UserId
        FOR xml path(''))
    , 1, 1,'') AS 'Result'
FROM MessageRecipients mr1
GROUP BY ConversationId
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple. I tried that, but I was adding it on the wrong location.Thank you. That worked perfectly.